# eror 500 when download pdf in shared hosting laravel

Tags: laravel, pdf, shared-hosting

when I'm trying to download pdf i get error 500 even all is working in my local machine
i'm on shared hosting is that can matter
route:

Route::get('/download-exercice/{id}/{cat_id}','teacher\Courses_Controller@download_exercice')->name('download_exercice');
controller:

```
 public function download_exercice(Request $request,$id,$cat_id){
        $course=$request->route('id');
        $cat=$request->route('cat_id');
        $categorie=Course_category::find($cat_id);
        $item=$categorie->classe()->where('course_id',$course)->first();
        $classe=Classe::where('id',$item->pivot->classe_id)->first();
        $ex=$item->pivot->exercice;
        $file=public_path()."/exercices/$ex";
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type: application/pdf',
          );
          return Response::download($file, 'cv.pdf', $headers);
       

    }
```

view:

```
 <form action="{{route('download_exercice',['course_id'=>$item->pivot->course_id,'cat_id'=>$item->pivot->categorie_id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                            <button value="submit" class="download_button">
                                              <a href=""><i class="fas fa-download"></i></a>
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
```

Comment: What is the error? You can check `storage/logs/laravel.log` for exact error and the stack trace.

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI i get no error just 500 page

Comment: Open this file `storage/logs/laravel.log` and check the exact error

Comment: So, your error does not belong to laravel, it's the server error. You can check the exact error message in your cpanel or directadmin panel

Comment: set `debug=true` in your `env` file and you will get the error. Then update the question with the error message.

Comment: @MohsenNazari is it true